# Unable to scan the DynamoDB in lambda function python

Tags: python, dynamodb-queries

Am writing a code in lambda function using python to scan my dynamo DB and provide the output as a holiday  or no holiday,I need my code to scan the DB and provide the date but whatever the scenario am getting only no holiday as result, Can anyone help me in this, below is my code

```py
import boto3
import json
import decimal
import datetime
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.resource ('dynamodb')

    dynamodb = boto3.resource ('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
    

    table = dynamodb.Table('Fulldate')

    getdate = datetime.date.today().strftime ('%d-%m-%Y')

    scan_kwargs = {
         'FilterExpression': Key('Fulldate').eq('getdate'),
         
}
   
    response = table.scan (**scan_kwargs)
    
    if response['Items'] :
        return response['Items'] ['holidayname']
    else:
        return "no holiday"
```

and DB has two columns as below
fulldate   holidayname
30.04.2021  testholiday
01052021    testholiday2

I have set the primary key for the full date column. and table name also Full date.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Still I get noholiday as the value output even if I today date in Db as holiday. Code not scanning the Db properly only returns value as no holiday